# How to sum the similar data based on id in foreach loop

Tags: php, mysql, foreach, addition

I have such a scenario where 
there is a loop in that loop i m getting 3 DIFFERENT data and each having different no of quantity:
like:
total data based on id:
2
is count
2

total data based on id:
5
is count
2

total data based on id:
6
is count
1
so what I want is I want to addd that count to show 5 i.e.(2+2+1 => counts)

Query I done like:

```
foreach($test as $user)
            {
                echo "total data based on id:";
                    //echo $user;
                    echo "<pre>";
                    print_r($user->id);
                    echo "</pre>";
                    echo "<br>";    
    $enroll_count =  $this->dbop->countcustomQuery("SELECT *  FROM data where userid='".$user->id."' and DATE(created_on) = CURDATE() - 1");

                  echo "is count";

                    echo "<pre>";
                    print_r($enroll_count);
                    echo "</pre>";
}                   echo "<br>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Just replace = with =+ after `enroll_count` .It solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can use PHP OO to do that in a clean way, follow the below steps: 
1. Create a class 
2. Create two variables id and count, keep their visibility to private in order to encapsulate the data. 
3. Create accessors and mutators (getters and setters). 
4. Call the mutators (setter) to set your data in various objects.
4. Now, loop for all objects.
5. Each time get the count using accessor (getter) and add it up to some other variable (you may call it total).